# Find the solutions of second derivative

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, fractions

If $$f(x)=\frac {2x}{x^{2}-3x+2}$$ find the solutions of
$$f''(x)=0$$
This problem is from a test. Is it possible to solve this without a calculator and without hard work? Maybe this fraction can be decomposed somehow?
I have the same question for this function
$$g(x)=\frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x-2}$$

Answer (score 4):

Partial fractions give

$$f(x) = \frac{-2}{x-1} + \frac{4}{x-2}.$$

Then

$$f''(x) = \frac{-4}{(x-1)^3} + \frac{8}{(x-2)^3}.$$

The numerator of that, after you add the fractions is $x^3-6x+6,$  which doesn't have pretty roots.  The real root is $-(\sqrt[3]{4}+\sqrt[3]{2}).$

Comment: got any idea for g(x)?

Comment: @Andrei  You might substitute $t=x-2$ and see if the derivatives are easier.